# Markov chain transition matrix with each row the same?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-theory, markov-chains

In my linear algebra class, we were learning about Markov chains, and the prof. put a confusing question on the board. Namely, can one have a transition matrix in which each row is the same, i.e., let's say for a $3 \times 3$ matrix, each row is $[a,b,c]$, with the constraint being that $a + b +c  =1$. Is this possible? Further, what if the values of $a,b,c$ are the same as the values of the steady-state vector?

Comment: Why not?  It might be a peculiar  Markov chain, but the matrix fits all the conditions.

Answer (score 2):

The values $a,b,c$ *are* going to be the values of the steady state vector - we can think about this as such: in the long run, the probability from going from any state to state 1 is $a$, and correspondingly $b$ and $c$ for states 2 and 3 respectively.

The transition matrix you mentioned is definitely a valid transition matrix. The only requirement is that each row sums to 1.

Answer (score 2):

A Markov chain $X_1, X_2, \dots$ with a transition matrix in which each row is the same
corresponds to the special case in which each $X_i$ is *independent* of $X_{i-1}.$

In general, a Markov chain has
$$P(X_i = x_i|X_{i-1}=x_{i-1},\, X_{i-2} = x_{i-2},\, \dots,\, X_{i-k} = x_{i-l}) = P(X_i = x_i|X_{i-1}=x_{i-1}),$$
so colloquially, dependence is only on the most recent specified step. However,
there is no *requirement* for any dependence at all. An sequence of independent random variables can be Markovian.

*Note:* The power $P^n$ of a Markov chain shows $n$-step transition probabilities. Some Markov chains have the property that $P^n,$ for sufficiently large $n,$ has rows that are *very nearly* the same, indicating that
$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} P^n$ exists. This means that, with sufficient
passage of time, the state of a Markov chain at step $n$ does not depend
on its initial state at step $1.$ A chain with such limiting distribution
is called *ergodic.*